# Can't access Vue from js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-resource

I'm trying to create an App with Vue, and Vue-ressource
Actually i need to use ressource to made auth system by an API call.
But in my Auth.js (that i import into my login.vue) console said he can't read $http of undefined. So apparantly i can't reach 'this' (so vue).
Did i missed something ? Or its just a bad use ?

Thank you all

actually my main.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
Vue.use(VueResource)

import App from './components/App.vue'

import Login from './components/Login.vue'
import Home from './components/Containers.vue'


function requireAuth (to, from, next) {
  if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
    next({
      path: '/',
      query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
    })
  } else {
    next()
  }
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    { path: '/home', name: 'home', component: Home, beforeEnter: requireAuth },
    { path: '/', component: Login },
    { path: '/logout',
      beforeEnter (to, from, next) {
        auth.logout()
        next('/')
      }}
  ]
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

the login.vue

```
import auth from '../utils/auth'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      pass: '',
      error: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login () {
      auth.login(this.email, this.pass, loggedIn => {
        if (!loggedIn) {
          this.error = true
        } else {
          console.log('good')
          this.$router.replace('/home')
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

and my auth.js where the vue-ressource post is made :

```
export default {
  login (email, pass, cb) {
    cb = arguments[arguments.length - 1]
    if (localStorage.token) {
      if (cb) cb(true)
      this.onChange(true)
      return
    }
    pretendRequest(email, pass, (res) => {
      if (res.authenticated) {
        localStorage.token = res.token
        if (cb) cb(true)
        this.onChange(true)
      } else {
        if (cb) cb(false)
        this.onChange(false)
      }
    })
  },

  getToken () {
    return localStorage.token
  },

  logout (cb) {
    delete localStorage.token
    if (cb) cb()
    this.onChange(false)
  },

  loggedIn () {
    return !!localStorage.token
  },

  onChange () {}

}

function pretendRequest (email, pass, cb) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.$http.post('localhost:9000/api/login', {email: email, password: pass}).then(response => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        cb({
          authenticated: true,
          token: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
        })
      } else {
        cb({ authenticated: false })
      }
    }, response => {
      console.log('error ' + response.status)
    })
  }, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Replace vue-resource with axios. Easy to do. Vue-resource is not longer maintained by Vue team, so it's bad choice to use it.( https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4#.dwmy5ymjx )

   Axios is widely supported. https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios .

   Nice laracasts about using axios with vue. You will quickly get it. https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/18
2. It is normal that you can't access Vue instance in your auth module. Try to learn more about using `this` and you will quickly get it 'why?'
3. To make ajax requests in your auth module, just import axios and use `axios.post` / `axios.get`

Any questions? Comment and I will explain more.

Comment: 1.Thanks for all the tips !

2. i have changed for axios so, i don't know that vue-resource was not supported anymore.

3. So if i understand well, this can not have vue into my auth JS because its not the same context ? right ? (if you have some link for explainaition :) )

Comment: any questions? If it works for you always remember to upvote and accept answer. It enables other users to find right answers etc.

Comment: yep i press enter to fast :p just look my first comment :)

Comment: 3. yes. exactly. it's all about context. As you are beginner it is worth to learn about context in ES6. Start with modules (which you already doing) and then learn about arrow functions and things like `let` . It will help you a lot